# Matrix Multiplication $A*A^T$ = $A^T*A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a Matrix A, is it true that $AA^T$ = $A^TA$? $A^T$ is the transpose of A.
If this is not always true, under that condition is this true?

Comment: It is not true in general. A simple counterexample is $$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ If $A$ is a real matrix, the condition under which it is true (by definition) is that $A$ is a [normal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix)

Comment: If $A$ is not square, $AA^T$ and $A^T A$ aren't even of the same size...

Answer (score 1):

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}\\
A^T = \begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix}\\
A A^T = \begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}\\
A^T A = \begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}\\
$$

Comment: Not a fan of this answer. I think mentioning some intuition as to why it doesn't hold might be useful, or a mention of normal matrices.

Comment: @RushabhMehta You could always leave one yourself.